# How to automatically add data series to line chart when new row of data added to underlying sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a line chart where the X-axis is Day of Week and Y-axis is a count. The underlying sheet has Sunday dates in column A, where each row is one week apart, and columns B-H have count values for Sunday through Saturday, one week per row.

The sheet auto-updates as new data comes in, but not the chart.

In Chart Editor > Setup > Data range I specified A1:H1000, and when I click the Add Series button at the bottom the chart editor readily offers up the new rows (i.e. I don't have to specify the cell ranges, they are already detected) but I do have to explicitly click each one to add them to the chart.

**Is there a way to bypass this final manual step, so the chart draws a new data series line whenever a new row of data is added to the underlying sheet?**